# TensorFlow, Implementing Solution

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm new to Python, Machine Learning and TensorFlow and feeling very overwhelmed!

I'm still working on the MNIST dataset and have the following code (which I've complied from the TensorFlow tutorials):

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data',one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y,y_))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for i in range(10):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_:mnist.test.labels}))
```

My question is, from here, how do I extract the solution to make a usable application? By which I mean, how do I get to the stage where I can feed it one image and get one prediction of a number out based on the training of the MNIST dataset.

Many thanks

Comment: In case it matters I am running Python 3.5 on Windows 10 and have TensorFlow version 0.12,

Answer (score 0):

With your code it should work like this:

`test_prediction = y.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})`

If you want to have "your own images", you have to make sure they are the same format as your mnist.test.images variable. In this case, you can replace mnist.test.images in the code above by any Numpy array filled with arrays with length 787 (image of 28 by 28 pixels). 
Please let me know if this works!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the following to my code `test_prediction = y.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.validation.images})
print(tf.argmax(test_prediction,1).eval())` and this gives me a list of the predicted values :)  But, I'm still in the InteractiveSession. Can I now export the solution to work outside of TensorFlow?

Comment: Great that it works! What do you mean "work outside of Tensorflow"? As you are using Tensorflow operations you always need to use them if you deploy this solution somewhere ;) If you have a specific question about how to use this program somewhere else (for example with Flask) you can post a new question!

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to try and explain what I mean and then hopefully you can let me know if I need to start a new question. I want a self-contained solution that will run outside of the tensorflow interactive session, for example a function, where I can send new queries and get predictions back. I don't want to have to retrain the network every time I have a new image to analyse.

Comment: Hey jlt199. After your for loop, you have a trained model (whooo!). After this training you could supply all images in a folder, or start a flask server that queries this model, or whatever you want! Right now you indeed have to run your script again every time you want to re-run another folder. Luckily, you can save and load your weights: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/

Comment: Weights and bias saved and restored, thanks :)  Next, can I use these values to create a network outside of an interactive session?

Comment: Check out this page on Tensorflow sessions: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management